# How to bind port 8090 via ssh to open a remote ip adress locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, port, darknet

I am training a CNN remotely via AWS EC2, and I want to track the process of training via an ip address.

I am training darknet, and using [this command](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects) that should enable me to view the training:

(to see the mAP & Loss-chart during training on remote server without GUI, use command `darknet.exe detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -mjpeg_port 8090 -map` then open URL http://ip-address:8090 in Chrome/Firefox browser)

How can I bind this port locally so that I can open the ip address on my laptop and track the process?

I tried the following:

`ssh -L 3000:127.0.0.1:8090 user@ec2-...-.compute.amazonaws.com`

But it gives me the error 'permission denied(publickey)' (I ran this from my local computer from the .ssh folder).

I do not get this error when I connect to my instance via SSH.

Comment: Do you provide the correct username when setting up SSH tunnel? (In your example you are using the username "user")

Comment: I am using ubuntu, which is the same what I use when I connect to the instance.

Comment: Have you tried adding the ssh-key to memory before running the SSH tunnel command? I.e "ssh-add /path/to/your/key.pem".

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have done it, and now I do not get the permission denied message anymore. However, when I open http://ip-address:8090, it still says ip-address’s server IP address could not be found...

Comment: Cool! Should you not be connecting to localhost in your web browser? localhost:3000 or localhost:8090 or something?